# Can groupby work case sensitive in OData?

Tags: odata

I want to take via OData a list of different Ids from a database table. I am doing http://localhost/app.web/odata/MyEntity?$apply=groupby((Id))

Id has folling values: AA12345 and aa12345 (same value but one capitalized and the other one not capitalized). I am getting from group by only one value (the not capitalized one). How can I tell OData that it should return both values?

Comment: What is the backend that your odata feed is pulling from? Sql Server, for instance, allows you to specify a [COLLATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) which includes CI or CS (Case Insensitive / Case Sensitive) in your schema at various levels (server default, database default, table, column). That setting determines the behavior, odata does nothing more than construct the query and pass it off to the db server.

Comment: The database is Sql Server. Ok, I hoped that I could specify in the OData query if I want to group data case sensitive or insensitive.